# hero unit bootstrap with hover effect

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently making a build where I'm using the hero unit for bootstrap. the image that's in it is responsive and I'm trying to add hover animations with divs within the hero unit, but can't make the divs inside respond with scaling within the hero unit.

```
<script>
  $(function() {
      $("#dequeue div").hover(function(){
          $(this).animate({ right:'50px',
  opacity:'0.5',
  height:'150px',
  width:'200px' });
      }, function() {
          $(this).animate({ right:'0px',
  opacity:'1',
  height:'100px',
  width:'150px' });
      });
  });
</script>

  <div class="hero-unit">
    <img src="img/homepage.jpg" alt="">
          <div id="dequeue" class="blocks">
           <div class="one"></div>
        </div>
  </div>

#dequeue {
    position: relative; top:44px;  float: left; z-index: 1000; 
}
.blocks div { width: 200px; height: 100px; margin: 0 0 5px 0; }
.one { background: #ccc; position: relative; z-index: 1000;}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `inherit` instead of static values to give the divs some of the properties of their responsive parents?

Comment: even with inherit it's not reacting the way I want it to. the div doesn't size down along with the rest of the site

Comment: Wait - why are you using divs for the hover animations? Why not apply them directly to the image?

Comment: within the div there's going to be a stopwatch that's going to be counting up. i guess if i can't figure this out i'm going to suggest having the animation be an static image